# ReactCSSTransitionGroup with React 0.14 and pretty Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...)

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Well, I used to do some job in ReactJS with ES3 syntax. Now I'm trying my best with ES6 one but I can't simply use ReactCSSTransitionGroup, due to absolutely mad error that says

> Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's 'render' method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.

What is that?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

    render(){
     return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={transitions}>
      <Content/>
    </ReactTransition> 
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm experiencing something similar and the standard explanation of "you've somehow included React more than once" doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: Seems I am not a unique snowflake after all. My approach is below.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I was using the `external` setting in my webpack config to exclude `react` and `react-dom` so that I could include them separately but `react-addons-css-transition-group` seems to reference `react` through a non-standard route and so the reference was not getting externalised properly.

I changed approach to using Webpack's [vendor bundle](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code) approach with `react`, `react-dom` and `react-addons-css-transition-group` in the vendor bundle and that seems to work for me.

Comment: Did you get to figure out what's wrong with how `react-addons-css-transition-group` requires `react`? It still happens in v15.4...

Comment: It has been a while but I think that the issue is that it uses an internal require path as it is itself in the `react` module. It doesn't do `require('react')`. 

I think that the `react-addons-css-transition-group` code is shipped inside the `react` module. The `react-addons-css-transition-group` just exports the right bit from within react. I think that's right.